# Get Auth0 user's complete Guardian phone number from Management API

Tags: oauth-2.0, auth0

I'm using [Auth0](https://auth0.com/) as my authentication provider. I've enabled Guardian to facilitate SMS based MFA (Multi Factor Authentication). When a new user signs up,
 [Auth0](https://auth0.com/) registers their phone number.

My system provides users the option of opting into SMS messaging on topics of interest to them. Unfortunately when I query the Management API I'm given a masked version of the phone number (i.e. `"+61 XXXXX2407"`). I would like to get their complete phone number as registered from [Auth0](https://auth0.com/) rather than asking them to enter it again.

How can I go about retrieving the complete phone number from [Auth0](https://auth0.com/)'s Guardian?

Comment: Hey Frank, did you find a way to receive full phone number? I'm facing the same issue at the moment.

Comment: Hey @skymk, I ended up reaching put to Auth0 directly and they informed me that they have no plans in the short term to make this available. Short answer, no for the foreseeable future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After two years, Auth0 finally provide a feature to disable phone number obfuscation. :)

Given a management API token with the proper permitted scope, this is how to get the user's phone number used in MFA:

1. Send `PATCH /api/v2/tenants/settings` to disable the phone number obfuscation.

The request body should contain:

```json
{
  "flags": { 
    "disable_management_api_sms_obfuscation": true
  }
}
```

2. Send `GET /api/v2/users/{id}/enrollments` to get the user's *first* confirmed MFA enrollment ID.

The `id` field is the user id. The response body should contain an MFA enrollment id. For MFA using SMS, you would want an id that begins with `sms|dev_`. Save this id for the next step.

3. Send `GET /api/v2/guardian/enrollments/{id}`

The `id` field is the MFA enrollment id. The phone number should now be deobfuscated.

Reference:

[Getting Users Phone Number](https://community.auth0.com/t/getting-users-phone-numbers/12628/9)

Footnote:

[As recently discussed here](https://community.auth0.com/t/when-will-api-v2-users-userid-authenticators-be-documented/52722), to get all authenticators by a user, you would use `GET /api/v2/users/{id}/authenticators`. The response will include the entry obtained in the step 2 above. However, this is not documented yet as of now.